# Chained conditional count in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks at how a form has been filled out. Here's an example:

```
ID   Name   Postcode  Street        Employer  Salary     
1    John   NaN       Craven Road   NaN          NaN
2    Sue    TD2       NAN           NaN        15000
3    Jimmy  MW6       Blake Street  Bank       40000
4    Laura  QE2       Mill Lane     NaN        20000
5    Sam    NW2       Duke Avenue   Farms      35000
6    Jordan SE6       NaN           NaN          NaN
7    NaN    CB2       NaN           Startup      NaN `
```

I want to return a count of successively filled out columns on the condition that all previous columns have been filled. The final output should look something like:

```
Name   Postcode   Street   Employer    salary
  6           5        3          2         2
```

Is there a good Pandas way of doing this? I suppose there could be a way of applying a mask so that if any previous boolean is given as zero the current column is also zero and then counting that but I'm not sure if that is the best way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `notnull` and `cummin`:

```
In [99]: df.notnull().cummin(axis=1).sum(axis=0)
Out[99]: 
Name        6
Postcode    5
Street      3
Employer    2
Salary      2
dtype: int64
```

Although note that I had to replace your NAN (Sue's street) with a float NaN before I did that, and I assumed that ID was your index.

The cumulative minimum is one way to implement "applying a mask so that if any previous boolean is given as zero the current column is also zero", as you predicted would work.

Comment: Better than mine.

Comment: Although I'm somewhat curious to know how `cummin(axis=1)` works the way it does. The first axis seemingly has no role to play here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `cumprod` BTW you have 'NAN' in your df, I try then as `notnull` here

```
df.notnull().cumprod(1).sum()
Out[59]: 
ID          7
Name        6
Postcode    5
Street      4
Employer    2
Salary      2
dtype: int64
```